# Cannot create database diagram in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to create my first database and see its diagram. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 and I think I managed to create the database itself, but I am having trouble creating the diagram. This is exactly what I did:

I opened `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, hit `File`, then `New` and then `Query with Current Connection`. I entered the following code to create a dummy database, just so I can visualize the diagram.

```
CREATE DATABASE CarDatabase;

CREATE TABLE Car(
    CarID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CarName VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Car(CarID, CarName)
VALUES(1, 'Mercedes');
INSERT INTO Car(CarID, CarName)
VALUES(2, 'BMW');
INSERT INTO Car(CarID, CarName)
VALUES(3, 'Porche');

SELECT * FROM Car;

CREATE TABLE Engines(
    EngineID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EngineName VARCHAR(255),
    CarID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Car(CarID)
);

INSERT INTO Engines(EngineID, EngineName, CarID)
VALUES(1, 'Maybach S 400 4MATIC', 1);

SELECT * FROM Engines;
```

The above selects seemed to work just fine, so I think the code is ok. After a few searches on the internet I found out about what I need to do to generate that diagram, so that's what I did. On the left-hand side, in the `Object Explorer`, I expanded the Databases file and then I could see my database 'CarDatabase'. After I expanded this, I could see a file 'Database Diagrams'. I right clicked on it and installed the necessary support for database diagrams. Now I right click again and hit `New Database Diagram`. A window pops up. Here, I should see my tables (`Car` and `Engines`) and then I would select which ones I want in the diagram and then I would have these tables created in a diagram. The problem is that after clicking on 'New Database Diagram' none of my tables are shown in this window. I have nothing to select. I saw nothing about this in the tutorials I watched on the internet. I am for sure missing something, but I have no idea what. I couldn't find anything about it. I tried saving, closing the studio and then opening it again and it didn't work. I refreshed the cache (`Edit` -> `IntelliSense` -> `Refresh Local Cache`) and still nothing. I tried creating other databases (multiple times) hoping it would get solved, but still this issue persists.

[image]

[image]

What I am expecting to get is a diagram like the following:

[image]

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using.  Diagrams were removed in 18.0 but brought back in 18.1.

Comment: @squillman It's 18.9.2

Comment: Also, 15.0.2000? Please apply [CU13](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100809) - friends don't let friends run RTM. Wouldn't hurt to [update SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#download-ssms), too.

Comment: The script you show above doesn't USE the database after you create it so they may have been created in the wrong database

Comment: Diagrams work just fine for me too in SSMS 18.9.2.  I think @MartinSmith might have nailed it.

Comment: Nice eyes @MartinSmith. I guessed wrong schema but wrong database is definitely a more plausible explanation. Check the _other database_ you were in when you created this database. _That's_ where your objects are.

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry for being an idiot, but how can I USE the database after I created it? Again, I apologize if it's a stupid question, but I'm completely new to this thing. Also, you said that they (I assume the tables) may have been created in the wrong database. Is there any way I can check where is what?

Comment: @AaronBertrand How can I check which objects (I assume you refer to tables) are where? And how can I create the objects in the database I initially intended? Sorry for these dumb questions but again, I'm a newbie at this stuff and am a bit lost. Thanks a lot.

Comment: SELECT DB_NAME() will tell you where you are now. Like Martin said you need to USE CarDatabase in order to create your objects there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, entering `SELECT DB_NAME()` in a query revealed which database I was working in. Also, I found that to change the database I am working in I can enter the command `USE <my_database_name>` and it changes. After doing these things the tables appeared in that window and the diagram worked. Thank you very much! Also thank you, @MartinSmith

Answer (score 0):

You may click "refesh" in the add table window and see if it shows you tables to select. This is a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: If you answer to old questions, check the questions, comments and eventually other answers, and evaluate if your answer add something new and valuable for other users. In this case in the comments there are insights about the issue, and the user realized that he use a wrong DB.